# Python 2.7 How to get all residuals out of a list received from Polyfit

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

currently I have big Arrays (1051 Elements) for x,y and z. 
My aim is to fit the best polynominal function for x,y,z respective -> t (time = 1051) in steps of 10.

To find out, which degree is the best fit, I gave the polyfit method the parameter full=True. So I get the residuals of the least square fit. I save all the results of polyfit in a list called fkt = [].

My Problem now is that I want to extract only the residuals of the entries in this list. I tried it with
`residuals = np.array(fkt[:][1][0])` resulting in only two values.
 However the indecies seem to be right! Since one of the values is the residual of the first Element.

My Question now: Do I have to iterate threw the list to get all Residuals, or does anyone have maybe a proposal how I could use a np.array instead of a list??

PS: Explanation of the Fkt list

1. First index []: different fitting / results of polyfit! 1051 / 10 =
   105 Entries
2. Second index []: 0=coefficients for the polynominal
   functions, 1=residuals and co (bonus information, full=True)
3. Third index []: 0=residuals

   ```
   x = rKnee[:,0,3]        #x-coordinate of the Translation
   y = rKnee[:,1,3]        #y-coordinate of the Translation
   z = rKnee[:,2,3]        #z-coordinate of the Translation

   pos = 0
   deg = 1                 #Number of Polynominals to be fit
   n = x.size
   t = np.arange(n)   #creates an Array for the Time t
   fkt = []

   while pos < n:
       fkt.append(np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(t[pos:(pos+steps)],x[pos:(pos+steps)],deg,full=True))
       pos += steps
   residuals = np.array(fkt[:][1][0])
   print residuals
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       computeSegmentation()
   ```

I am now already able, to get all 105 Elements containing the Full Information (including residuals) `residuals = np.asarray(fkt)`
`print len(residuals[:,1])` So Now I have 105 Lists as Elements in an numpy Array looking like this

> [ [array([ 0.00431193]), 2, array([ 1.35754456,  0.39632407]), 
>   2.2204460492503131e-15]
>
> [array([ 0.07957901]), 2, array([ 1.40745857,  0.13805929]), 2.2204460492503131e-15]

However I only need the first Entry of the list (the Residual)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
    while pos < n:
    coeff,bonus = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(t[pos:(pos+steps)],mag[pos:(pos+steps)],deg,full=True)
    fkt.append(coeff)
    res.append(bonus[0])
    pos += steps
print res
```

Give me only the first entries of the bonus information I get in polyfit full=True